# Hibernate entities not being found unless manually specified in persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two applications,

```
App - main app : depends on lib
lib - secondary app.
```

Using spring boot i am generating the executable jar file for app, such that lib's jar is in the jar's lib folder  (my.jar!/lib/lib.jar)

I am using hibernate, with the following configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
    depends-on="fakeJpaProperties,fakeDataSource">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fake" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
        <bean class="my.persistence.MergingPersistenceUnitManager">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath*:META-INF/fake/persistence.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.path.to.lib.data.card" />
</bean>
```

And the following persistence.xml is in lib

```
<persistence-unit name="fake" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>fake</non-jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>
```

With this persistence.xml in app

```
<persistence-unit name="fake" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>fake</non-jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <jar-file>lib/lib.jar</jar-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

I am however getting a :

```
  org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: my.path.to.lib.data.card.FakeData
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2565)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2504)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2495)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1043)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1023)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1104)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

The exception doesn't work if i add:  `<class>my.path.to.lib.data.card.FakeData</class>` in the lib's persistence.xml.  I wouldn't like to have to specify all the entities manually however, which is why my entityManagerFactory contains the `"packagesToScan"`, however it seems that this is not being scanned.

How can i get the packagestoScan to work?

---

**Edit:**

I found [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/124419-packagestoscan-in-localcontainerentitymanagerfactorybea-doesn-t-work-if) that if `persistence.xml` is present, `packagesToScan` is ignored. In my case i cannot remove all the `persistence.xml` due to dependency on several other shared projects that need it. Is there a way to specify a package/wildcard rather than list each individual `<class>` in persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify a package/wildcard rather than list each individual  in persistence.xml?

AFAIK that is the way JPA is specified, so if you go with persistence.xml that's what you have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the @EntityScan annotation to you spring boot configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages="my.path.to.lib.data.card")
public class application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(application.class, args);
    }

}
```